# Can we have a class type for a generic?

Tags: java, generics

Say we have the function:

```
<T> T   getFromCache (ClassType<T>   clazz);
```

For strings:

```
String str =   getFromCache(String.class);
```

For maps what I am currently thinking of doing:

```
//… 
Map<String, SomeData>   anotherMapObject  = getFromCache( HashMap.class);
```

Can   we be more specific than this ?

One solution ofcourse  is to wrap  ‘HashMap’ in one class.  But if we don’t want to do that then is there a better solution ?

Comment: I can't quite puzzle out what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: the function in question is  function to get an object from Cache. (We seialize byteArray to an object then typecast it to given generics before returning.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the map implementation to be passed in you can do this:

```
private <M extends Map> Map<String, String> get(Class<M> m) throws Exception {
        return (Map<String, String>) m.newInstance();
    }
```

You can parametrize the key and value types like this:

```
private <M extends Map<K, V>, K, V> M getMap(Class<M> m, Class<K> k, Class<V> v)
```

Comment: That's gross... (I'm not saying there's a better way, it's just gross...)

Comment: LOL I agree, just trying to answer his question.